# Programmatically adjust row width on DataGridView to prevent ellipsis

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that loads lots of data, and I'd like it to do something that is in practice equivalent to setting a particular column's `AutoSizeMode` to `AllCells`, but without the performance penalty.

I think I should be able to see which cells are visible by capturing the `CellPainting` event, which will fire for currently visible cells. Also, since I'm using "Consolas" font which is monospaced, and I know all values will be single lined, measuring any sample string should be enough to calculate the proper width of the cell.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
private int MaxLength;

private void DataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    // DatabaseLog.Columns.Text is the index of the column I want to adjust the width for
    if (e.ColumnIndex == DatabaseLog.Columns.Text && e.FormattedValue is string text && text.Length > MaxLength)
    {
        text += "-"; // Just to be safe
        MaxLength = text.Length;
        // And to be extra safe measure it both ways and use the largest one:
        var width1 = (int)Math.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.CellStyle.Font).Width); // To be even safer use Ceiling
        var width2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, e.CellStyle.Font).Width;
        // Use a task in case DataGridView doesn't want to repaint since this is CellPainting
        Task.Run(() => BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>                
            dataGridView.Columns[DatabaseLog.Columns.Text].Width = Math.Max(width1, width2) + e.CellStyle.Padding.Horizontal // Also, add padding
        )));
    }
}
```

Which, on lines longer than about 100 characters will still show an ellipsis. If I change the line `text += "-";` to `text += "-----";` it works, but since that's just an arbitrary number of characters, there's no way to tell if it'll work all the time. So I wonder if there's anything I'm missing here that I should add to my width.

Comment: you could do this / set this after binding the data and before the Gridview has been displayed I have done this actually last week on several datagridviews make sure you have to propery's for the display at design time for setting the columns to what the default is vs making it adjust based on the Column Header or Row data width for example..

Comment: @MethodMan Sorry I don't get it. What exactly should I do after binding/before showing the grid view?

Comment: is this winforms or .aspnet web app.. if it's winforms you put the code in the `OnShowing` event.. if it's web forms you could to in to the pre_Init event

Comment: @MethodMan This is WinForms. Which code should I put on the `OnShowing` event?

Comment: you need to add the code before exiting the onshowing event that resizes all of the columns that you want to be resized via code.